# How to prevent AppBar from overriding custom status bar color

Tags: flutter, statusbar, appbar

I cannot change the status bar color, seemingly because the AppBar keeps overriding it.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(), // this component sets a status bar color and brightness
    body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>( // this component fails to
                                                 // override the status bar color
                                                 // and brightness set by the AppBar
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
      ),
      child: Container()
    )
  );
}
```

When I comment out the AppBar, the status color becomes blue. When I un-comment it, the status bar color stays blue but it is impossible to change it again. It seems like the AppBar locks the current color.

In the child widget, I tried using [setSystemUIOverlayStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html) before returning my component but it doesn't help:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
  ));
  return Container();
}
```

How do I set the status bar color when there is an AppBar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your root widget with `SafeArea`
for more details about the widget [click here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)